# How to get database data from PowerBi dataset?

Tags: c#, database, powerbi, metadata, powerbi-datasource

I need to get dynamically the metadata and data of the database (datasource??) used in a Power Bi dataset but I don't know how to do it. I mean the schemas, tables, columns etc... of the database, like the photo below (I can see them when I'm editing a tile)

[image: List of Database Tables]

First I have created a dataset from a Microsoft sample.
I was looking in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/ for an API that can helps me but I can only get the dataset ID with Get Datasets API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getdatasets)

```
{
  "@odata.context": "http://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/$metadata#datasets",
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "name": "Human Resources Sample",
      "addRowsAPIEnabled": false,
      "configuredBy": "eleonora---------@------.com",
      "isRefreshable": true,
      "isEffectiveIdentityRequired": false,
      "isEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired": false,
      "targetStorageMode": "Abf"
    }
  ]
}
```

or Get Dataset ():

```
{
  "@odata.context": "http://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/$metadata#datasets/$entity",
  "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "name": "Human Resources Sample",
  "configuredBy": "eleonora---------@------.com",
  "isRefreshable": true,
  "isEffectiveIdentityRequired": false,
  "isEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired": false,
  "targetStorageMode": "Abf"
}
```

but with the Get Parameters or Get Dataresource I get nothing

```
{
  "@odata.context": "http://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/$metadata#datasources",
  "value": []
}
```

There is a way to get the database from the ID of a dataset? Or getting it in another way?

Many thanks

Comment: What about this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getdataset?  Please, so the code you're using to get the (meta)data

Comment: Yeah this return the same, but an object instead of an Array, For now i'm just trying the APIs in order to know how to develop it. [Question updated]

Comment: Do you see this information when you are looking from Power BI web portal, in the settings for the dataset?

Comment: For example, I see it when I'm editing a tile [Question updated]

Comment: What you showed with the last question update is the schema of the model. This isn't the "database/datasource". If you want to see the datasource information, this is the "connection string" used to connect to the database (e.g. myserver.database.windows.net). If you want to see the list of datasets, the tables in each of them, and the columns in each table, currently you can't do this via Power BI REST API.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov exists a way to get them without Power BI REST API?

Comment: There is no other API that you can use. You can try to parse the XML in the pbix file, but this isn't supported and you should do it on your own risk.